# how to change cell color depending on row value in an Apex oracle sql query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I have a simple report

[image]

i want the cells with Bulk Quantity less than 20 to have a RED background. At the moment i have a simple select statement.

select BULK_QUANTITY, STOCK_NAME, FLOOR_ID, STOCK_ID from Bulk_stock

I am using the Apex Oracle software. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [LINK](http://blog.eberapp.com/ords/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:5983100346022749)

I think that's where you will find the solution to the problem